# How to check whether specific value exists in request in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm stuck in checking whether a specific value exists in the request. I'm doing like this,

```
foreach ($variant->sale_channels as $v_sale_channel) {
            $v_sale_channel->enabled = ($request->has('sale_channels_enabled.'.$v_sale_channel->sale_channel_id)) ? true : false;
            $variant_sale_channels[] =  $v_sale_channel;
        }
```

Am I doing it wrong `$request->has('sale_channels_enabled.'.$v_sale_channel->sale_channel_id)`

`sale_channels_enabled` is an array which contains only sale channel id's. I want to check weather a specific value exists in that array or not.

Comment: Please show result of `dd($request->sale_channels_enabled)`

Comment: I have this data `0 => 369acc19359b48898b320048867317b3
  1=> fd87de4107ab456cba956ba8a0e51f2e`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array($v_sale_channel->sale_channel_id, $request->sale_channels_enabled))
```